# pgfplots: Draw area of summed up percentages (like 'ybar stacked', but area style)

Tags: pgfplots

Sorry for the title, but I didn't know, how to explain my problem properly.

I want to have a filled area plot, like in chapter 4.4.9 (Area Plots) of the pgfplots manual, but with summed up percentages as values.

So, I want to sum up, f.i. all percentage values for 2005 etc.

The `ybar stacked` works well, but I want the same with filled areas.

Here is a working minimal example, that creates first the ybar stacked, and then my try for the ybar stacked area, that doesn't work as expected:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{pgf}                    
\usepackage{tikz}                   % tikz graphics
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{
Year,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4
2005,0,0.29,21.97,42.22,27.98
2006,0,1.43,8.25,47.53,29.96
2007,0.05,0.05,13.62,45.26,34.05
2008,0.06,0.89,10.63,30.84,44.63
2009,0.09,0,7.71,30.82,46.75
2010,0,0,1.65,28.34,27.02
2011,0,0,0.94,29.02,7.64
}\data

\begin{figure} [tb]%
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
        \begin{axis}[
                ybar stacked,
            grid=major,
            xlabel={Year},
            ylabel={\%},            
            enlarge y limits={abs=0},                       
            xtick=data,
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},          
        ]
        \addplot+[ybar, blue, fill=blue] table [x=Year, y=1] {\data};
        \addplot+[ybar] table [x=Year, y=1.1] {\data};
        \addplot+[ybar] table [x=Year, y=1.2] {\data};
        \addplot+[ybar] table [x=Year, y=1.3] {\data};
        \addplot+[ybar] table [x=Year, y=1.4] {\data};      
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ybar stacked}
\label{fig:pdf-test2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure} [tb]%
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
        \begin{axis}[
                stack plots=y,
                area style,         
                xlabel={Year},
                ylabel={\%},            
                enlarge x limits=false,             
                legend pos=outer north east,            
                x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},          
            ]
            \addplot table [x=Year, y=1] {\data};
            \addplot table [x=Year, y=1.1] {\data};             
            \addplot table [x=Year, y=1.2] {\data};
            \addplot table [x=Year, y=1.3] {\data};
            \addplot table [x=Year, y=1.4] {\data};     
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ybar stacked area}
\label{fig:pdf-test3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You almost have it, except for the fact that you're missing the `\closedcycle` commands that need to be added to the end of your `\addplot` commands in order to properly fill the areas under the curves:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}     
    \begin{axis}[
            stack plots=y,
            area style,         
            xlabel={Year},
            ylabel={\%},            
            enlarge x limits=false,
            enlarge y limits=upper,         
            legend pos=outer north east,            
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},          
        ]
        \addplot table [x=Year, y=1] {\data} \closedcycle;
        \addplot table [x=Year, y=1.1] {\data} \closedcycle;             
        \addplot table [x=Year, y=1.2] {\data} \closedcycle;
        \addplot table [x=Year, y=1.3] {\data} \closedcycle;
        \addplot table [x=Year, y=1.4] {\data} \closedcycle;     
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Side note: If you supply `ybar stacked` to the `axis` options, you don't need to add `ybar` to each of your series. That is set automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I call a useful answer ;)